# Toggle disabled attribute if select box option has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a submit button that's disabled by default and has a grayed out image in the src attribute.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form>
<select id="item_location">
    <option value="">- Choose Destination -</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="CN">Canada</option>
    <option value="IN">International</option>
</select>

<input class="submit" type="image" src="http://website.com/images/btn_buynow_LG--disabled.png" border="0" name="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

By default, the user must select the country. When a country is selected that has a value,  I'd like to update the image and remove the disabled attribute as long as the value of the dropdown option isn't blank.

Here's the jQuery I've come up with so far but it needs to toggle the disabled attribute based on the value of the select `item_location` select box.

```
function submitButton() {
    jQuery(".submit").change(function() {
        if (jQuery("#item_location") !== "" {
            jQuery(".submit").attr("src", "http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif").removeAttr("disabled");     
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
jQuery(".submit").prop("disabled", jQuery("#item_location").val() === "")
```

This will disable the `submit`, in case the `item_location` value is empty, else enabled.

**UPDATE**

```
// Cache the submit button
var $submit = jQuery(".submit");

// Disable the button based on the dropdown value
$submit.prop("disabled", jQuery("#item_location").val() === "");

// Change the src image, based on disabled attribute of submit button
$submit.prop("src", function (i, val) {
    return $submit.prop("disabled") ? 'old_image_src' : 'new_image_src';
});
```

Comment: How do I add to this that when the disabled attribute is removed, I need to change the src image?

Comment: I've tried your updated method here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yHxtp and I can't get it to work either. :/

Comment: Okay, I do see it working properly on the fiddle. But why is it giving me this console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`?

Comment: I think, since you are using `jQuery` as alias, but in the fiddle I am using `$`. Try adding `var $ = jQuery;` at the top and try again..

Answer (score 0):

use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get selected value of drop-down list

```
if (jQuery("#item_location").val() !== "") {
                             ^           ^ //added ) here
```

or better use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
jQuery(".submit").prop("disabled", jQuery("#item_location").val() === "")
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

---

Updated after OP's comment

```
jQuery(".submit").prop("src", "http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif");
```

Comment: What about changing the default image? I have a grayed out image that needs to be present only when the submit button has disabled attribute.

Comment: So I would need two `.prop()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
jQuery("#item_location").change(function() {
    if (this.value) {
        jQuery(".submit").prop("src", "http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif").removeAttr("disabled"); 
    }

})
```

Comment: no errors. Just nothing happens when I select one of the countries.

Comment: Strage. I can get it to work here:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGtLq but not in my original code. Is there a way to toggle back the disabled attribute if the value goes back to nothing?